# Loop not ending when using a size_t variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, size-t

I used a size_t variable to help me do my project. However, it's not working for all the cases I want and I really don't know what's the problem.

I use this 'for' instruction to check the bits from an unsigned long long "map", but when `t` variable gets to be 1, and the `j` is between 7 ( 1 * 8 - 1) and 0 ( (1 - 1) * 8 ), `j` also gets the -1, -2, -3, -4 and -5 values even if the condition is `j >= (t - 1) * sizeof(unsigned long long)`, which for the 't = 1' case is `j >= 0`. I really have no idea why, I replaced, for the case t = 1, the size_t with an int, but I would really like to know why is this happening, what am I doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```
int t; //( it gets values between 8 and 1 )
...
for ( size_t j = t * sizeof(unsigned long long) - 1; 
      j >= (t - 1) * sizeof(unsigned long long); 
      j--) {
    map_mask = help64 << j;
    printf("%zd ",j); // that s how i figured out i get negative numbers
                      //checking bit by bit and return 0(not fitting) if we see any bit equal
    if ( (map_mask & (*map)) == map_mask ) {
        mask8 = help8 << k;
        if ( (mask8 & p) == mask8 )
            return 0;
    }
    k-- ;// a variable i used for the mask( i initiated it with k = 7, it doesnt matter here
}
```

Comment: i will edit my post :) good question . i declared t like that : int t;

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned` type, so it can never become negative.

Comment: i know that, that's why i'm just out of ideas on how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from unsigned integer wraparound.

```
for (unsigned j = 7; j>=0; j--)
{ //whatever 
}
```

So when `j` is 0, you enter the loop, do the processing, then decrement it.  Since `j` is unsigned, it does not become, -1, but 0xFFFF.... (`(1<<sizeof(size_t))-1`) which is very big and definitely greater than 0.

The best solution is to use a signed type.  You probably don't need all the bits of size_t, Unless `t`  might be larger than `SIZE_MAX/sizeof(long long)`

You say `t` is between 1 and 8. `sizeof(unsigned long long)` is almost certainly no more than 16.  So the possible range of `j` is 0..128.  You can put that in a regular signed int, (or even a signed char) with no problem.

Comment: `t<=0` should be `t>=0`.

Comment: Now i got that, thanks for the answear. So should i use an integer instead for this case ? Or do you have any other method to treat this case ?

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest pattern for counting down using unsigned types is IMHO:

```
size_t idx;
for(idx = xxx*CHAR_BIT; idx-- >0; ) {
    ...    
    }
```

---

This way you avoid expressions containing `-1` or`+1` , while guaranteeing that the loop variable will **never** ever be out of bounds (even if the initial value would be zero ...)

Answer (score 0):

The type `size_t` is unsigned and so it should not be used as

```
printf("%zd ", j);      // signed version
```

it should be

```
printf("%zu ", j);      // unsigned version
```

If you want the `signed` version you can use `ssize_t` which is able to represent the number -1, and can be returned by functions as a way to indicate error.

It can be dangerous to use an `unsigned` variable in a loop that counts downwards.

Comment: Thanks for that :) I got that now, but i still get negative j even if i have a j >= 0 condition for no reason and that's my main problem.

Comment: @ballow No, the main problem is not `j` becoming "negative".  Yes it is _a_ problem, but the main one: using "continue until j negative" as the terminating condition.

Comment: @ballow I touched on that in the last sentence of this answer. Variable `j` has to become `< 0` for the loop to terminate, which is a problem if `j` is `unsigned`.